# Dual owner for directory

Tags: centos, acl, chown

How can I make a folder with two owners?

I need my folder to have privileges for two users: "ftpuser" and "apache". How can I do this?

My OS is Centos 5.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. But you can give access to "ftpuser", and only for him, with the command

```
setfacl -R -m u:ftpuser:rwx /path/to/dir
setfacl -R -d -m u:ftpuser:rwx /path/to/dir
```

This requires group write access on this dir, which can be set with the command

```
chmod g+w -R /path/to/dir
```